# HSQL DB Declaring variables using created types

Tags: hsqldb

I am converting PL/SQL stored procedures into HSQLDB procedures. I am trying to declare variables inside my procedure that references that I have created. When I use this type for a parameter to the procedure, it works fine. But when I try to use it as a local variable type, it does not know how to use it.

Example:

```
CREATE TYPE MY_DECLARED_TYPE AS INTEGER;

CREATE PROCEDURE TEST (IN TEMP MY_DECLARED_TYPE) MODIFIES SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SET 1
   BEGIN ATOMIC
      DECLARE l_var_1 MY_DECLARED_TYPE;
   BEGIN ATOMIC
      --Do some stuff--
END;
```

Is there some clause in HSQLDB that does not allow for the use of declared types in a declare statement? Or is there something else that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in the latest HSQLDB version (2.3.4).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST (IN TEMP MY_DECLARED_TYPE) MODIFIES SQL DATA DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
   BEGIN ATOMIC
      DECLARE  IVAR MY_DECLARED_TYPE;
   BEGIN ATOMIC
      SET IVAR = 0;
   END;
END;
```

Comment: I can't upgrade to that version, but I will accept the answer :). Thanks